# How can you loop over a list of fields to find if they have a value?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a service that update a customer's address. To limit changes in the database (and have a clean audit/changelog), I do not want to update up-to-date fields.

The entities are **Contact**, which is updated using a **CustomerAddress** (MS Dynamics entities).
(an alternative solution could be an entity-framework flag I do not know about.)

I currently have :

```
Dim newcontact = new Contact with {.id = (someguid)}
Dim oldcontact = obtainOldContact(someguid) 
Dim customerUpdate = obtainChange(someguid)

if oldcontact.City <> customerUpdate.City then
    newContact.City = customerUpdate.City
end if
[repeat for about 12 fields)
```

(which I find somewhat horrible)

A simple solution would be :

```
Dim newcontact = new Contact with {.id = (someguid)}
Dim oldcontact = obtainOldContact(someguid) 
Dim customerUpdate = obtainChange(someguid)
Dim isDirty as boolean = false

if oldcontact.City <> customerUpdate.City then
    newContact.City = customerUpdate.City
    isDirty = true
end if
[repeat for about 12 fields)
```

(which I find too horrible)

What I though about doing is checking if my *might-be-updated* fields have a value, but I can't figure how :

```
'newcontact = my contact to _maybe_ save...)
dim listProp = {"Adress1Line1", "Adresse1Line2", "PostalCode", "City"}
for each properties in listProp
    if eval(newcontact & "." & properties) isnot nothing then ' <- kinda what I wanna do
        'update and exit for
    end if
next
```

Any elegant solutions is welcome.

Comment: The isDirty should be a property of Contact. newContact should be a copy of oldContact and the property City should set the isDirty to true if the new value is different.

Comment: I'm not adding a flag to Contact. NewContact cannot be a copy a oldContact exactly because of what I explained at first. I need newContact to contains its ID and changed value only.

Comment: Could you use the [GetProperties()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method of your object type to iterate them?

Comment: @j.f. : Apparently, it's what I needed to get started. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I followed j.f.'s comment with `GetProperties()`.

Here's how I ended up doing it :

```
Private Function UpdateProperties(Of T)(fieldList As Dictionary(Of String, String), Current As T, UpdateObject As T, Change As CustomerAddress) As Boolean

    Dim isDirty = False
    Dim PropList = GetType(T).GetProperties()
    Dim CustomerPropList = GetType(CustomerAddress).GetProperties()

    For Each item In fieldList
        Dim prop = item
        Dim propT = PropList.Single(Function(e) e.Name = prop.Value)
        Dim propCustomer = CustomerPropList.Single(Function(e) e.Name = prop.Key)

        Dim val As String = TryCast(propT.GetValue(Current, Nothing), String)
        Dim valCustomer As String = TryCast(propCustomer.GetValue(Change, Nothing), String)

        If val <> valCustomer Then
            propT.SetValue(UpdateObject, valCustomer, Nothing)
            isDirty = True
        End If
    Next

    Return isDirty

End Function
```

Where

- `fieldList` is a dictionnary that maps my 1st object's fields (Contact/Account) to the 2nd object's fields (CustomerAddress).
- `Current` is what I currently have saved for my customer
- `UpdateObject` is an empty object that will contains only info that have changed
- `Change` is the info received that I might need to use to change my current data (if different)